# Pycharm перестал реагировать на изменения в js файле

Tags: pycharm, javascript

Имеется проект на питоне. В нем также используются js файлы. Собственно, проблема такова - несмотря на вносимые в джаваскриптовый файл изменения, после нажатия на кнопку Run в IDE этот файл обрабатываеся так, как будто застыл в некоторм предыдущем состоянии. Pycharm 3.1

Comment: @kraft_lawrence, что подразумевается под "обрабатывается"?

Comment: Ну да, не в IDE обрабатывается, конечно, а сам скрипт в браузе выполняется не должным образом.

Answer (score 1):

[@kraft_lawrence](/users/14650/kraft_lawrence), скорее всего он кэшируется на стороне браузера. Добавляйте рандомный get-параметр, чтобы этого не происходило (`print '<script src="/js/superscript.js?rand=%s"></script>' % random_string`)